# Azure DevOps Maximum number of Repos & Pipelines support

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

I am working on a project automation where there will be maximum of 500 Repos & CI/CD Pipelines created under a particular Azure DevOps Project. Does it support that much number of Repos & Pipelines under the DevOps project? What is the maximum limit of creating number of Repos & Pipelines in a project of Azure DevOps?

I tried to create Repos & Pipelines in DevOps project and I am expecting 500 numbers of Repos & CI/CD Pipelines to create in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it support that much number of Repos & Pipelines under the DevOps project?

Yes. Azure DevOps supports creating 500 Repos & CI/CD Pipelines under a project.

> What is the maximum limit of creating number of Repos & Pipelines in a project of Azure DevOps?

Azure DevOps has no limit on the number of repo and pipeline definitions.

For Azure repo, It only suggests that the size of the repo should not exceed 10GB. Refer to this doc: [Git limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops)

And it's not a hard limit.

For Azure Pipeline, there is a limit on how many pipelines you can concurrently execute,and that is tied to your licensing. Refer to this doc: [Pipelines - rate limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops#pipelines)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can only have up to 2000 repos. As azure devOp sent me an email when I reached that limit, eversince I couldnot create new repos.