# Practical Limitations on Number of Repos in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I am working to setup a large number of Azure DevOps repos, and I read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642863/azure-devops-maximum-number-of-repos-pipelines-support) that there are no limitations on the number of repos one can create. If that's true, at what point will I start to see performance degradation in ADO, due to a large number of repos?

Comment: What is a "large number"? 100? 1000? 10,000? More?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps Maximum number of Repos & Pipelines support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642863/azure-devops-maximum-number-of-repos-pipelines-support)

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Practical Limitations on Number of Repos in Azure DevOps?

As you have learned, Azure devops has no limit on the number of repos, only on the size of the repo.

> Repositories should be no larger than 250GB.
>
> We **recommend keeping your repository below 10GB** for optimal operation.
> If your repository exceeds this size consider using Git-LFS, Scalar,
> or Azure Artifacts to refactor your development artifacts.

On the flip side, when you have more than a certain number of repos and don't exceed the size limit, you already have a lot of trouble managing them.

So limiting the number doesn't really make sense.